# How to hande button press in UIAlertView

Tags: ios

I have a `UIAlertView`.
When the user taps on one of its buttons, I want to detect this.

What do I need to do to get notified of the button press?

Comment: Check `UIAlertViewDelegate` methods

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007548

You should abstract the `UIAlertViewDelegate` in your .h file

Like this:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

And when you are creating your `UIAlertView` set it's `delegate` to `self`.

And then you will have a delegates (thats how you get notified)

Please NOTE: That `UIAlertView` and it's delegates Will Be DERPRECATED.
Use `UIALertController` in order to support future iOS 9 
Which is already in Beta.

If you are targeting anything lower than iOS 8, you must still use `UIAlertView`

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertController

Comment: You are referencing information that relates to the iOS 9 SDK, which is still in beta. Currently IMHO you should be assuming, that people on Stackoverflow are looking for information on current iOS versions. It certainly can't hurt to mention that `UIAlertView` **will be** deprecated as of iOS 9. If you are targeting anything lower than iOS 8, you **must** still use `UIAlertView`. Also don't provide links against prerelease documentation, since that's likely going to disappear from the web as soon as the stable version is released.

Comment: @TimBodeit Thanks for targeting the issues fixed as suggested